# How to customize a Capacitor official plugin native implementation

Tags: android, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I'm developing an app with (Ionic) Capacitor and the resizeOnFullScreen option of the official Keyboard plugin doesn't work for me (windowTranslucentStatus), so I had to do a small tweak in the native Android code to get it working, Keyboard.java:

```
private int computeUsableHeight() {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    mChildOfContent.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
    // return isOverlays() ? r.bottom : r.height();
    return r.bottom;
}
```

However, Gradle imports that file from node_modules, in capacitor.settings.gradle:

```
// DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE! IT IS GENERATED EACH TIME "capacitor update" IS RUN
...

include ':capacitor-keyboard'
project(':capacitor-keyboard').projectDir = new File('../node_modules/@capacitor/keyboard/android')
```

which means that the changes will get lost in the next checkout/upgrade... as the file is not tracked by Git.

I'd like to keep the rest of the Keyboard plugin (js and ios) there, but, somehow "eject" the Android code on the repository and customize it.

Is it possible? Is there an official way of doing this kind of thing? It looks to me that it goes with the philosophy of Capacitor, but I couldn't find anything on the docs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up "ejecting" the plugin myself:

1. I copied the folder node_modules/@capacitor/keyboard/android to android/local-capacitor-keyboard and the file node_modules/@capacitor/keyboard/LICENSE to android/local-capacitor-keyboard/LICENSE. Note that the "local-" prefix is not arbitrary, if the folder is just "capacitor-keyboard" or starts with "capacitor-keyboard-" Android Studio shows a funny project structure.
2. Added a line at the end of android/settings.gradle pointing to that folder (so npx cap sync does not brake anything):

   ```
    include ':app'
    include ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins'
    project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins').projectDir = new File('./capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/')

    apply from: 'capacitor.settings.gradle'

    project(':capacitor-keyboard').projectDir = new File('./local-capacitor-keyboard/')
   ```
3. And pressed the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button in Android Studio
   [image]

I'll keep an eye on node_modules/@capacitor/keyboard/android on upgrades.

I still don't know if there is an official/better way...

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution: making a local copy of the whole plugin. It gives you better control over the plugin (eg. customize js) and a package.json upgrade won't break your code. The trick is in `yarn add file:...`

The steps are:

1. Copy the plugin to a local folder. You can take it from node_modules or from the official repository. And the local folder can be inside your project, which is great because you don't need an especial directory structure to build (so you can use CI normally for example).

   I chose a folder called `plugins`:

   ```
   cp -r node_modules/@capacitor/keyboard/ plugins
   ```
2. Rename the package name. In my example, set in `plugins/keyboard/package.json`:

   ```
   "name": "local-capacitor-keyboard"
   ```
3. Remove the remote package and install the local:

   ```
   yarn remove @capacitor/keyboard
   yarn add file:plugins/keyboard/
   npx cap sync
   ```

   "Sync Project with Gradle Files" in Android Studio
4. Customize at will and build using your standard commands.

Note that the plugin gets copied from plugins/keyboard to node_modules/local-capacitor-keyboard when you add it, so if you want to bring updates you have to re-add it:

```
yarn add file:plugins/keyboard/
```

**BONUS**

You can `link` the plugin during development, so the local copy is actually used during the builds (and shown in Android Studio for edition):

```
cd plugins/keyboard/
yarn link
cd ../..
yarn link local-capacitor-keyboard
npx cap sync
```

"Sync Project with Gradle Files" in Android Studio

Notes:

- It has to be added as well as linked for `npx cap sync` to pick it.
- You can unlink them running:

  ```
  yarn unlink local-capacitor-keyboard
  cd plugins/keyboard/
  yarn unlink
  cd ../..      
  yarn add file:plugins/keyboard/
  npx cap sync
  ```